# css: flexbox last row has double the height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I played a bit with flexboxes and tried to imitate a LaTeX-like table with top/mid/bottomrule. I like that the table is scaling nicely and shift to a list-like display on small screens.

However, I noticed that, if I use a whitespace in a cell's text content, the cell's height might double or even triple without any aparent reason.

Is there a flexbox-property that I overlooked and can help me fix this behavior? Why is this additional height even generated?

Screenshot:
[image]

Snippet:

```css
div.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
div.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
div.head {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
div.item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="head">Col 1</div>
    <div class="head">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="item">Cell2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 3</div>
    <div class="item">Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: put a space beetween Cell2(make it "cell 2"), the problem is the space into the words

Comment: Note that it's not the height of the last row that's doubled (as stated in your title). It's the height of the second row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, initially, `.row` is sized taking only the contents of `.item`s into account. Then `.item`s flex, and become equally wide due to `flex: 1`. But the contents weren't equally wide, so the longest will wrap to a second line.

It's better shown in this example:

```css
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 2px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">Cell 11111</div>
  <div class="item">Cell 2</div>
  (before flex)
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
  <div class="item flex">Cell 11111</div>
  <div class="item flex">Cell 2</div>
  (after flex)
</div>
```

In your example you have `Cell 1` (with space) and `Cell2` (without), which produces the difference.

Eventually the `.row` also flexes and thus a new line is no longer needed, but it seems browsers don't detect that. It's hard to say, but I think this is right. That's because

1. The [hypothetical main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-main-size) (height) of the rows is calculated, and

   > If a cross size is needed to determine the main size (e.g. when the
   >   flex item’s main size is in its block axis) and the flex item’s cross
   >   size is auto and not definite, in this calculation use fit-content as
   >   the flex item’s cross size.
2. [Rows flex](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths). This determines their used height.
3. [Cross sizes (widths) are determined](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-manip). The rows are stretched to fill the table horizontally. But its too late, heights have already been calculated.

Since your column layout won't wrap because `.table` has an auto height, I would just use the default `flex-wrap: nowrap`. It fixes the problem because now the flex container will be single-line, and thus the widths of the rows will be [definite](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite):

> If a single-line flex container has a definite cross size, the outer
>   cross size of any stretched flex items is the flex container’s inner
>   cross size (clamped to the flex item’s min and max cross size) and is
>   considered definite.

```css
div.table {
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```css
div.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
div.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
div.head {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
div.item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="head">Col 1</div>
    <div class="head">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="item">Cell2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 3</div>
    <div class="item">Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also try explicitly providing an explicit width:

```css
div.row {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or even preventing text wrapping with `whitespace: nowrap`.

Comment: Why doesn't this behavior occur in the first or third rows?

Comment: @Michael_B Because in other rows, both `.item`s have the same width before flexing.

Comment: @Michael_B You also need some space (soft wrap opportunity), or `word-break: break-all` to break inside words.

Comment: Yes, I noticed early on that space characters matter. I just wasn't sure why. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: Also, just FYI, Edge and IE11 do detect and adjust for the flexing, thus rendering the expected layout.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks for the reply! Both `.row{width:100%}` and `.table{flex-flow: column}` fix the problem and seem to lead to identical output. However, since `.row{width:100%}` would basically fix the wrong `wrap` command, I prefer the `.table{flex-flow: column}` solution. Since I would like items to wrap in rows and words to wrap in items, `whitespace: nowrap` seems to be no solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `div.item` from `flex: 1;` to only `flex-grow:1;`.

Here's the working snippet.

```css
div.table {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
div.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div.head {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 2px 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
div.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="head">Col 1</div>
    <div class="head">Col 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 1</div>
    <div class="item">Cell2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">Cell 3</div>
    <div class="item">Cell 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```